# Objective-C: How to create object instance with constructor that references arrays

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create an array of objects, but it's not working as expected. I have a Person class with a name property and I'm trying to instantiate Person objects with the names from another array like the code below. Instead of the names in the names array being used, the program outputs "(null)". So that means that it's not working as expected.

ViewController.m

```
names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mike", @"John", @"Jimmy", @"Tim", nil];
personsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:[names objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [person name]); // outputs "(null)"

    [personsArray addObject:person];
}
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {

  if (self = [super init]) {
      name = name;
  }

     return self;
  }

  @end
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

Please help!

Comment: What's coin and where is his instantiation ?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to change my variable names. Updated.

Comment: What does the Person class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `-[Person initWithName:]` is your problem:

> ```
>       name = name;
> ```

You are just assigning the argument variable to itself. You need to assign the instance variable. You probably want to copy the input string, so:

```
_name = [name copy];
```

Comment: I would suggest that instead of calling `copy` explicitly, declare the `name` property with `copy` instead of `strong`.

Comment: Then you'd have to declare the property `readwrite` (perhaps just in a class extension) and use the setter in the initializer. If the property is intended to be read-only, that's extra work and executable size for no particularly good reason.

Comment: The property is already declared as readwrite (that's the default over readonly) but I did forget the line would need to be `self.name = name;` for the declared `copy` to kick in.

Comment: When I answered, he hadn't added the property declaration. I agree that if it's `readwrite`, it should be `copy`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user298519 Please don't forget to accept answers that solves your questions. You haven't accepted a single answer to any of your questions in over a year.